# How so I pull all chapters out from this NSSting using regular expression RegEx?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to pull ANY characters out from the middle of this string (as seen in bold):

t_product_name:["**xxx yyy zzz 111 222 333**"],

Here is the code I'm trying but it's not working for me. What am I doing wrong with my RegEx?

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"t_product_name:[\"(.*)\"]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:html options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

   // detect
   NSString *insideString = [html substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

   //print
   NSLog(@"t_product_name: %@", insideString); }];
```

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression for this? Just find the index of the two `"` characters and pull the substring from that range.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lazy quantifier ? like this and escape `[]` double square brackets.

**Regex:** `t_product_name:\[\"(.*?)\"\]`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI3pB8/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use a **negated** character class:

```
t_product_name:\["([^\"]+)"\]
```

The inner part says: do match everything except a double quote (it does not need to be escaped in square brackets but will need to be escaped in your string), see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qS8jO6/1).